# Do I write for SOME $k \in \Bbb Z$ or for ALL $k \in \Bbb Z$?

Tags: linear-algebra

When I want to say that if $x$ is even, then $x = 2k$, am I supposed to say for SOME $k \in \Bbb Z$ or for ALL $k \in \Bbb Z$?

Comment: Need to say "some" since can't say $x=2k$ for all $k$ [makes no sense]

Comment: I'd say "There exists $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=2k$"... Which is both precise and easy to write in first order logic.

Comment: Ask yourself what would be true for x if the statement were true for two different integers.